# Filter or Sorting multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If i have two array as following:

```
$array1 = array(array('id'=>11,'name'=>'Name1'),array('id'=>22,'name'=>'Name2'), array('id'=>33,'name'=>'Name3'),array('id'=>44,'name'=>'Name4'),array('id'=>55,'name'=>'Name5'));

$array2 = array(array('id'=>22,'name'=>'Name2'),array('id'=>55,'name'=>'Name5'));
```

My expect result, the array2 should be always at the beginning :

```
$newarray = array(array('id'=>22,'name'=>'Name2'),array('id'=>55,'name'=>'Name5'), array('id'=>11,'name'=>'Name1'), array('id'=>33,'name'=>'Name3'),array('id'=>44,'name'=>'Name4'));

My current solution is using two for loops:
foreach($array2 as $Key2 => $Value2) {       

    foreach($array1 as $Key1 => $Value1){            

        if($Value1['id'] != $Value2['id']) {
            //push array 

        }    
    }    
}
```

Edit:
The result "$newarray" should not include the duplicate ids from array1.

But i am looking for a faster and simpler solution.

**SOLUTION:**

$a1 = array(); 
foreach ($array1 as $v) $a1[$v['uuid']] = $v;

$a2 = array(); 
foreach ($array2 as $v) $a2[$v['uuid']] = $v;

$filtered = array_values(array_diff_key($a1, $a2)); 
//print_r($filtered);

$newarray = array_merge($array2, $filtered);

Thank you guys!!!!

Thanks.

Regards Jack

Comment: array_merge http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: you want to merge array but you don't want to repeat id's am I right ?

Comment: yes, i want to mearge hte array but no repeat id, and the array1 must always have to be at the top.

Answer (score 1):

you want `$new_array = array_merge($array2, $array1);` puts the second array onto the end of the first one

Comment: the result will have duplicate id

Comment: easiest way is to make sure each key for the outter array is the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function for that, like this:

```
$newarray = array_merge($array2, $array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement but to sort multi-dimensional array on some specific key 
You need to use `usort` function 
Try the code below:

```
$cmp = function ($a, $b){  
    $a_val = $a['id'];  
    $b_val = $b['id'];

    if ( $a_val == $b_val) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_val < $b_val) ? -1 : 1;
};
usort($array2,$cmp);
```

$array2 will be sorted by 'id'